# Issue with Phonegap Camera Plugin (DestinationType.FILE_URI)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing a phonegap based app which has file transfer functionality. I am using phonegap camera plugin for the selection of the image file. The code works fine with 'DestinationType.DATA_URL'. But I am unable to access the file with 'DestinationType.FILE_URI'.

DestinationType.DATA_URL just gives the image file content. But I have to get the image file name & file path along with its content. So I have to use 'DestinationType.FILE_URI' in the camera options. Below is my code,

```
function attachFile() {
 var pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
 var cameraOptions = { quality: 49 ,  destinationType:
 Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY };             
 navigator.camera.getPicture(attachSuccess, attachFail, cameraOptions);
}  

function attachSuccess(fileuri) {
 filePath = JSON.stringify(fileuri);
 console.log("FilePath: "+filePath ); 
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail); 
}

function attachFail() {
 console.log("attach failed");
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {            

  console.log("gotFS:");      
  var root = "/"+fileSystem.root.name;  
  console.log("root:  "+root); 
  filePath = filePath .substring(filePath.indexOf(root));        

  var imageName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/'));
  var type = imageName.substring(filePath.indexOf('.'));
  fileSystem.root.getFile(filePath, null, gotFileEntry, fail);  

}

function fail() {
  console.log("** failed **");   
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
  console.log("got file entry");
  fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file) {
  console.log("got file");       
}
```

When I call the 'attachFile' function, Get Picture window opens & I am able to select the image file. Then the attachSuccess callback function is getting executed. But I am unable to access the file with the FILE URI. The FILE URI is getting printed as below,

content://media/external/images/media/5490

I wonder how I can get the 'file name' or 'file object' from this URI. Please suggest.
(code tested in android Kitkat & Lollipop)

Comment: What do you mean by "access the file"? You want to get it's data as binary stream or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cordova's FileSystem API. Here's a quick example of how to load an image file:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, // The file path
    function(fileEntry) { // found the file
        fileEntry.file(function(f) { // got the file
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                var fileContent = reader.result;

                // Do something with the fileContent
                someImage.attr("src", fileContent); // Example
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(f); // TODO find a way to read it straight to the right format (if there is any)
        }, function(e) { // cannot open file
            console.log("Error opening file: " + e.message);
        });
    },
    function(e) { // file not found
        console.log("Error finding file: " + e.message);
    });
```

`fileContent` Is a string contains `'data:'` + base64 encoded string.
You can also use the `f` variable to get the file name.

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Answer (score 0):

The URI that you are getting is the native URI. Try removing destinationType field from your cameraOptions because the plugin defaults to FILE_URI.

If that doesn't work, give destinationType the value of 1.

I am guessing Camera.DestinationType object is somehow mixed up.

P.S. If your final goal is to upload the photo, try using cordova-plugin-file-transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty fine.

You should verify that either you have added **File** plugin details in **config.xml** or not. This could be the reason of not picking file details correctly.

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
```

and/or below one too, in case you want to transfer the file somewhere else.

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
```

Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510794/phonegap-filetransfer-error-code-returns-null?rq=1) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306533/uploading-picture-from-phonegap-cordova-app/27308998#27308998). Both had used `destinationType.FILE_URI` and were unable to process further but once correctly added plugin details in the **config.xml** it worked well.